# Checkbutton command binding to wrong values when instantiated in loop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When I click on a checkbutton in my project, it is not executing the correct functionality. The project can be found at https://github.com/shitwolfymakes/Endless-Sky-Mission-Builder/ (indev branch)

I am building an application using tkinter, and am working on a function to dynamically place ttk.Entry objects next to ttk.Checkbutton objects, and then link them together.

I have already rewritten this function a few times, and even added a special case for when self.numMandatory is 0, but nothing has worked.

This is taken from guiutils.py, line 323.

```py
# add the optional fields
for i in range(self.numMandatory, self.numFields):
    print(self.rowNum)
    self.listEntryStates.append(BooleanVar())
    self.listEntryData.append(StringVar())
    self.listEntryData[-1].set(self.listDefaultEntryData[i])

    self.listEntries.append(ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.listEntryData[-1], state=DISABLED, style="D.TEntry"))
    self.listEntries[-1].grid(row=self.rowNum, column=1, sticky="ew")

    #print(self.listEntryStates[-1])
    #print(self.listEntries)
    self.listCheckbuttons.append(ttk.Checkbutton(self, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=self.listEntryStates[-1],
                                                 command=lambda: self.cbValueChanged(self.listEntryStates[-1],
                                                                                     [self.listEntries[-1]])))
    self.listCheckbuttons[-1].grid(row=self.rowNum, column=2, sticky="e")

    print(self.listCheckbuttons[-1].__str__(), end=" is bound to: ")
    print(self.listEntries[-1].__str__(), self.listEntryStates[-1])

    self.rowNum += 1
# end for
```

This is taken from guiutils.py, line 349

```py
def cbValueChanged(self, entryState, modifiedWidgets):

    for widget in modifiedWidgets:
        print("The value of %s is:" % widget, end="\t\t")
        print(entryState.get())
        if type(widget) is str:
            break
        elif entryState.get() is True:
            widget.config(state='enabled', style='TEntry')
        elif entryState.get() is False:
            widget.config(state='disabled', style='D.TEntry')
    #end for

#end cbValueChanged
```

In the main window, when I scroll down and click "add trigger", the new window appears properly. But when I click on the checkbutton next to the Entry that says `"[<base#>]"`, that entry should be enabled by cbValueChanged.

For some reason, when the loop to add the optional fields runs, the command= section binds only the last entry in self.listEntries (but the entry it's binding each checkbutton to isn't created until the very last time through the loop)

I'm not sure where else I could ask a question like this, and I know this is asking more than most questions. If there is any more information you need, I'll be happy to provide it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You ~~can't~~ edit: shouldn't use `lambda` in a loop. Frankly you shouldn't use it at all. Use `functools.partial` or make a real closure.

```
from functools import partial
self.listCheckbuttons.append(ttk.Checkbutton(self, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=self.listEntryStates[-1],
                                             command=partial(self.cbValueChanged,self.listEntryStates[-1],[self.listEntries[-1]])))
```

Comment: `lambda` is late binding, just like a `def`. So `self.listEntries[-1]` means the last entry of self.listEntries *when you click*, therefore after the loop is finished. There's hacks to get around this using default arguments, but it's cleaner and clearer to use a real partial or real closure. That said the best way for this would probably be to trace the variable and not use the command at all.

Comment: _"you can't use lambda in a loop"_ is false. You can use it, you just have to understand the concept of closures. Also, _"you shouldn't use it at all"_ is very debatable. Personally I don't see any reason why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @BryanOakley IMO lambda is very unpythonic. Using a default argument to create a closure is very unintuitive and a hack at best. lambda makes for cryptic code that's hard to read, often only to save a couple lines of code, and often when a neat alternative like partial or itemgetter exists. If no alternative exists that's a pretty big clue that a def with an informative name, documentation and tests is probably needed. It has no advantages, and modern python should avoid it if possible (and also map, filter, and reduce).